# PowerBI DAX Switch & SelectedValue

Tags: powerbi, switch-statement, dax, selectedvalue

I'm experiencing an issue with a DAX code.

When I write the code as follows, I don't get any errors.

```
FilteredTableByRiskType =
**VAR SelectedRisk = "A"**
VAR FilteredTable =
FILTER(DB_Table,
        SWITCH(SelectedRisk ,
            "A", DB_Table[A]=1 ,
            "B", DB_Table[B] =1,
            "C", DB_Table[C]=1 ,
            "D", DB_Table[D] =1,
                        FALSE()
        )
)
RETURN
FilteredTable
```

However, if I write it like this, it returns an empty table. I'm also checking the SelectedRisk value in a table, and I'm able to retrieve it correctly.

```
FilteredTableByRiskType =
**VAR SelectedRisk = SELECTEDVALUE('Risk_Table'[Risk])**
VAR FilteredTable =
FILTER(DB_Table,
        SWITCH(SelectedRisk ,
            "A", DB_Table[A]=1 ,
            "B", DB_Table[B] =1,
            "C", DB_Table[C]=1 ,
            "D", DB_Table[D] =1,
                        FALSE()
        )
)
RETURN
FilteredTable
```

I also tried the following code for checking, and it returns "True."

```
IsTest = SELECTEDVALUE(Risk_Table[Risk])  = "A"
```

What can I do? Thank you.

I tried different methots.

Comment: Are you trying to calculate a table based on a user-selected value?

Comment: No, I want to filtering a table based on a user-selected value. If user select "A" value, table called "X" is filtered by "A" column. (X[A]=1)

Comment: How or where are you then using `[FilteredTableByRiskType]` ? And is it a Table or a Measure? What icon shows next to it? If it is a Table then it doesn't work that way. The Table gets calculated at refresh - it isn't dynamic or interactive.

Answer (score 1):

Your second table expression, using `SELECTEDVALUE`, returns no rows since that column probably has more than one value in it.

Unless you use the optional second parameter in `SELECTEDVALUE`, the function returns a blank if the referred column does not contain one single value.

The table expression does not take slicer selection into account when it calculates, which is why the part you are looking at evaluates correctly when used as a measure in a visual.

Note that you are trying to persist a calculated table to your data model - you cannot have a persisted table updated at query time (i.e. when you make slicer selections), calculated tables are *only* evaluated at processing time (i.e. when the report data is refreshed).

You can probably solve whatever you are attempting using measures instead.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are needing a Measure, try:

```
SelectedRiskType = 
  var selectedRisk = SELECTEDVALUE('Risk_Table'[Risk])
  var filterTable = FILTER(DB_Table,
        SWITCH(selectedRisk ,
            "A", DB_Table[A]=1 ,
            "B", DB_Table[B] =1,
            "C", DB_Table[C]=1 ,
            "D", DB_Table[D] =1,
                        FALSE()
        )
  )
  RETURN CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(DB_Table), filterTable)
```

This measure will return the number of rows matching your criteria, add this measure to your visual and/or add it to the visual filter pane.